# Differential of the product of two functions according to Leibniz

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In this Wikipedia article, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#Discovery, the following initial equation using differentials was apparently used by Leibniz to ultimately prove the product rule:

$d(u * v) = (u + du) * (v + dv) - u * v$

I understand the algebraic manipulation and cancelling that follows, but do not understand this above line. Is there some other theorem it is is referencing that I'm not aware of? I'm just not sure where the terms come from at all.

Thank you

Comment: BTW, note that "\cdot" gives you the vertically centered dot for multiplication: "\$ x\cdot y\$" produces "$x\cdot y$". But in this case you can just omit the symbol altogether and use the multiplication implied by juxtaposition (so just write $xy$ instead of $x\cdot y$).

Comment: Oh okay, thanks a lot! Sorry, I'm new around here! ;) @MPW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the basic idea is to measure how the expression changes when then dependent variables change:

(increment of expression) = (expression at incremented location) - (expression at original location)

The dependent variables change from $(u,v)$ to $(u+du,v+dv)$, so you are interested in computing $df \stackrel{\textrm{def}}{=} f(u+du,v+dv)-f(u,v)$. In this case, $f(u,v)=uv$.

Comment: Wow haha not sure how I missed that - was definitely overthinking it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

That is a simple application of notion of errors. Errors arise when we calculate some value. Such values are never exact; they have some errors.

In mathematics and physics, we denote the error in some quantity $A$ by $\Delta A$ or $dA$. Further, we write the final result as $A\pm\delta A$ to signify that the value can go $\Delta A$ units up or down.

Here, you have $u\cdot v = (u)(v)$. Write the errors alongside,
$$u\cdot v \pm\Delta ( u\cdot v) = (u\pm \Delta u)(v\pm\Delta v)$$
Replace $\Delta x$ by $dx$ and the $\pm$ signs to $+$ signs (because we wish to calculate the maximum error; this is a bit complicated, ask me if you have doubts), we have
$$u\cdot v + d(u\cdot v) = (u + du)(v + dv)$$
Just transpose $u\cdot v$,
$$d(u\cdot v) = (u+du)(v+dv) - u\cdot v\ \ \square$$